# Ruby / Rails find file with name like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i try to find all files in a directory which has a name like "test".

So in my directory (/test/files/example) i got following files:

- test_1
- test_2
- test_5
- test_9

How can i get all the files with the File Class in Ruby? I do this but i think you see the struggle

```
10.times do |count|
  file_path = "/test/files/example/test_#{count}.wav"
  if File.exist?(file_path)
    @files[count] = file_path
    next
  end
  break
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't `break` in your loop since you won't get past `test_2` in that case. Are you just wanting to collect their path names into the `@files` array? I don't "see the struggle" (other than the `break` problem) because it's unclear what your end goal is. You might want to look at [`Dir.glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

Comment: yeah already got an answer. But the struggle was that if in this case test_3 file isnt found it breaks. But without the break it runs 10 times also if he doesnt find anything

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Globbing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) is the way to go. This will return an array of filenames matching your pattern.

```
Dir["/test/files/example/test_*.wav"]
```

The return value is an array of strings, which you may sort however you like.

Comment: Wow thanks that was easy. Is there a way to sort them?

Comment: It's an array of strings. Sort them however you like.